# how to convert an object type column to datetime in panda

Tags: python, pandas

I have one column given as type object and want to convert it to a datetime:

DataFrame: **df**

Column: **date**

Value Format: **1880-01-01T00:00:00.000**

Dtype: **object**

When doing:
`df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dt['date'])`

I got the error:
**Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1583-01-01 00:00:00**

Even specifiyng the format:
`df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],  format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')`

I got the same error, any idea why that error occurs and how to solve it?

Comment: to get a styler for display: ` styler = df.style.format({"date": lambda t: t.strftime("%B %Y")}) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `1880-01-01T00:00:00.000`, it should work.
But from your error message, it seems that your value is `1583-01-01T00:00:00.000` and it is out of [pandas timestamps representation range](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/user_guide/timeseries.html#timestamp-limitations).
In nanosecond resolution, the timespan that can be represented using a 64-bit integer is limited to approximately 584 years, which is:

```
print(pd.Timestamp.min)
Output: 1677-09-21 00:12:43.145225

print(pd.Timestamp.max)
Output: 2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807
```

But if your value is `1880-01-01T00:00:00.000`, after specifying the format:
`df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])`,
when I print `df['date']`, I get:

```
1880-01-01 00:00:00
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: I have edited my answer based on the assumption that the value of the format you are trying to convert is `1583-01-01 00:00:00` as stated in your error message.

Comment: yes, that's it, the value given was just for showing the format of the value, i guess i can't work with those values then... thanks for the help though!